# Spring application on JBoss ActiveMQ artemis JMS deployment issue

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

Application EAR is not getting deployed on JBoss EAP 7.0.0 after including Spring Boot WAR in the EAR

Application uses JBOSS 7 ActiveMQ messaging service and works fine with no issues. But when we add WAR build using SpringBOOT in the application EAR and tries to deploy the EAR on cluster environment then EAR deployment is rolledback and we get exception.
Factory method 'artemisServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS.setConfiguration (Please refer complete exception trace)

The issue is with Spring boot autoconfiguration because when we removed spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar from the application class path then the deployment happened successfully and application is running fine. We want a mechanism where we can specifically disable Spring Boot ActiveMQ auto configuration.

Complete Exception Trace

```
Error creating bean with name 'artemisServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/artemis/ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS]: Factory method 'artemisServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS.setConfiguration(Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/core/config/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/server/embedded/EmbeddedJMS;
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
                at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:184)
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
                at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS]: Factory method 'artemisServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS.setConfiguration(Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/core/config/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/server/embedded/EmbeddedJMS;
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
                ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS.setConfiguration(Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/core/config/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/server/embedded/EmbeddedJMS;
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration.artemisServer(ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration.java:82)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$145801e2.CGLIB$artemisServer$2(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$145801e2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f9d0b616.invoke(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
                at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$145801e2.artemisServer(<generated>)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
                ... 29 more
```

Please suggest what can be done in this case

Comment: I don't think there's anything which the ActiveMQ or JBoss communities can do to address your desire for a mechanism where you can specifically disable Spring Boot ActiveMQ auto configuration.  You'll likely be best served by working directly with the Spring community on such a feature.

Comment: artemis is the broker of ActiveMQ used by Jboss. So we have configured artamis in the standalone.xml. So this problem is in the intersection of activmq, jboss and spring. As per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html 32.1.2 "Spring Boot can auto-configure a ConnectionFactory when it detects that Artemis is available on the classpath. If the broker is present, an embedded broker is started and configured automatically (unless the mode property has been explicitly set)" we tried setting the property all this but did not work.

Comment: It's a jar issue. which doesn't has this have this method. This method has been moved around look for this jar having : org.apache.activemq.artemis. either client or common. not sure here but that's the culprit for you either go for version 1.X or 2.X just check which one has this method.

Answer (score 0):

all.
I have used the below property to disable the auto configuration of ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration.class, which works for me. Hope this post will help for our upcoming folks.

*spring.artemis.embedded.enabled=false*

Thanks,
Faruk